# "Since $H^*(X)$ is a polynomial ring, $H^{q + 2^i} =0$ for $0 < 2^i <q$"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have some questions in the proof:

"Theorem: If $H^*(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is a polynomial ring or a truncated polynomial ring in a generator $x$ of dimension $q$, and $x^2 \neq 0$, then $q=2^k$ for some $k$.

Proof: 
Since $H^*(X)$ is a polynomial ring, $H^{q + 2^i} =0$ for $0 < 2^i <q$. Therefore $Sq^{2^i}x=0$ for $0<2^i<q$. But $Sq^{2^k} \neq 0$ for some $k$ such that $0<2^k \le q$. So $q=2^k$."

Could you help me to explain why "Since $H^*(X)$ is a polynomial ring,  $H^{q + 2^i} =0$ for $0 < 2^i <q$" ?

Answer (score 3):

If the cohomology ring is a polynomial ring or a truncated polynial ring *generated by an element of degree $q$*, then the cohomology groups of positive degree less that $q$ are obviously zero.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is your generator and $\deg(x)=q$, then you may only have nonzero cohomology groups $H^n(X)$ for $n$ a multiple of $q$, ($\deg(x^k)=kq$).  Since $q<q+2^i<2q$ for $0<2^i<q$, $H^{q+2^i}=0$.